# multiple intent filter to multiple activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

i have two activity associated with two buttons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">





    <activity

        android:name=".Subactivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:taskAffinity="com.example.start_cs.sub">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".sub"

        >
    </activity>

    <activity

        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" android:taskAffinity="com.example.start_cs.main"
        >

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />            </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".main"

        >
    </activity>


</application>
```

MainActivity code

```
package com.example.start_cs.myapp;




Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_text_view);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, main.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });

}
```

layout code

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/main"
    android:background="@drawable/main"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/main_text_view"


    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"


    />
```

in this situation

Subactivity button opened sub

but MainActivity button did not open main

but if i put MainActivity above Subactivity

Subactivity button did not open sub

but MainActivity button opened main

Comment: Post the relevant code.  A manifest file is not sufficient to control the actions of a button.  Are your buttons part of your app, or are you talking about launchers in android app menu?

Comment: buttons are a part of my app @rothloup

Comment: post layout file also, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, based on your responses to my comments, I guess all I can say is that you need to follow a tutorial on how to create an app for android.  There are excellent tutorials available all over the internet.

You have two activities, so you should have two layout files.  You only posted one.

You should also have two source files, one for each activity. You only posted one.

Every android element in a layout that you would like to reference in your code needs an ID.  your code references `R.id.main_text_view`, but your layout file has no such id in it.  I'm surprised your code even compiles.

However, to answer your specific question, what you need is the following:

1)  The `<name>` tags in your manifest file must match the name of your java class source files for each of your activities.  So your activity class files appear to be called "MainActivity" and "Subactivity" according to your manifest file.  However, see my comment on your onClickListener code below.

Also, your manifest indicates that both of your activies are "LAUNCHER" activities.  You only need that tag for activities which you want to be able to launch from the Android application launcher (i.e. the list of all the apps installed on your phone).  Seems like you would only want this on your main activity, but you could specify more than one if you like.

2)  Your activities are duals of each other (i.e. they sound like they do exactly the same thing - each has a button that launches the other) so the code will be very similar.  Your code for MainActivity should look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_text_view);  //<-- This tries to find a button in this activity (using the activity's layout file that was used in the call to setContentView() in onCreate().  However, the id you specify doesn't exist in your layout file.  This should either not compile or return null.

//This is fine.
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, main.class);  //<--"main.class" doesn't match either of the activity names declared in your manifest.  It should match one of the names declared in the <name> tag of one of your <activity> tags.
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });

}
```

Your layout file needs to contain an id for the button that wish to find using `findViewById()`.  Modify your layout file as follows (and create one for each activity - although you could, technically, reference the same layout for each activity.  But for now, it is conceptually easier to have separate files).

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/main"
android:background="@drawable/main"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:id="@+id/main_text_view"    <!--  Here is the line that identifies the button for your app.  The format is "@+id/some_name", and is reference as "R.id.some_name" in your code. -->


android:layout_marginTop="17dp"


/>
```

Now you must do the same in your sub-activity code, but your onClickListener will call the Main Activity instead of your subactivity.  So the onClickListener code looks like this for your MainActivity (which launches your subactivity):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Subactivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
```

and like this in your subactivity (which launches your Main Activity)

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
```

Comment: thank you for your time but i need to tell you that i have all my files and it worked very well but the issue is how can i use the two buttons at the same time only one button worked well only if i put it first of my manifest code as i said before and the other one did not work the issue only in manifest code i tried the code and it worked well with the first intent filter whatever if it MainActivity or Mainsub  @rothloup "i have all my xml and java files"

Comment: @mmorsy  The manifest is not code.  It does not determine the behavior of your buttons.  All it does (in your case) is declares the components of your app (activities, receivers, services, and such).  Just because you swap the order in the manifest and your get different behavior doesn't mean the solution lies in your manifest.  If you posted all of your files, then you are missing a lot of code and layout that is necessary to do what you describe.  I hope my answer helps to at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: my files     http://pasted.co/5834e7be - http://pasted.co/8afb9f92 - http://pasted.co/b82bcf8a - http://pasted.co/75bbd1b0 - http://pasted.co/0b791d98 - http://pasted.co/bf2ec691 - http://pasted.co/26db9cad - http://pasted.co/8adef098    @rothloup

Comment: ok a few notes.  First, review [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it is easier for someone to help you next time. Second, your "masaa" class has no code to set the listener for the button.  Third, both buttons appear to be defined in the same layout file "content_main".  Your "main" class uses "content_main", so it can find the button with id "main_text_view", but your "sabaa" class won't find the buttonwith id "masaa_text_view" because its in another layout file.

Comment: The state of your code and layout files indicates that you have a lot of confusion regarding how to create an app, and specifically how to handle layouts and intents.  The android developer documentation has a nice little [training tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) that covers exactly this topic.  I suggest you follow it so you can learn the basics - this will serve you much better than having someone fix your code for you.  You can also refer to the details in my answer to guide you.  I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: please i do not understand you please give me the solution to this problem that makes me over come this problem @rothloup          and thank you for your advice and time

Comment: @mmorsy  I've done all I can.  I pointed out all of the things in your code that need to be fixed.  The next step in helping you would be to provide you with a complete tutorial - and the comments section on Stack Overflow is a very poor place to do that.  I provided you with a link to a tutorial that the android developer website has that should help you.  I shouldn't be recommending specific external sources on this site, but since you appear very lost, check out Udacity.com.  There is a tutorial called "Developing Android Apps" that I think will help you.  It is very detailed and helpful.

Comment: @mmorsy  I wish you the best of luck.  Please visit and dive deeply into the content on each link I sent to you.  SO will be here to help you on your next question, but be sure to follow the guidelines that I posted a link to in one of my earlier comments.  It will help us help you.
If you have found my answer helpful, please upvote it (that is performed by clicking the "UP" arrow next to my answer).  If the answer solved your problem, please accept it (by clicking on the "checkmark" next to my answer).  That's how we say thanks on Stack Overflow!

Comment: how can i find simple hamburger menu article @rothloup

Comment: If you work through the tutorials I listed above, many of the questions you are asking will be answered.  I don't of a specific hamburger menu tutorial, but the concepts of menus in general are covered.

Comment: I received a notice that you tried to edit my answer by deleting all of the content and replacing it with your own answer.  Please don't do that.  Edits are intended to *clarify* an answer, not to replace it entirely.  If you like, you can write an answer to your own question.  I think that what you wrote in the edit would be most appropriate as a comment to my answer, since it explains what you did to solve your problem (mazel tov, by the way!) but my answer contains a lot of technical details that may be useful to anyone else facing similar problems that comes and reads your question.

Comment: is it fine now @rothloup